# How to connect to States from the shape file?

Tags: geospatial

I have a spatial file of the congressional districts of the US, however, the states are numbered in an unknown form. I have searched through all the other files but have found no key or description of the numbering of the states. Am I missing something?
Here is the link where I downloaded the files.[enter link description here](https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/tiger-line-shapefile-2016-nation-u-s-115th-congressional-district-national)

Comment: what is unknown about the form? looks like fips code to me.

Comment: You are going to have to be clearer herer. We cannot smell what *an unknown form* is. Please [edit] your question.

Comment: I'm new to tableau and have only taken a beginner's course on it. So I've never heard of fips code. So I'll look into it, thanks

Comment: better question for GIS.stackexchange? if so, I'll migrate it.

Comment: @philshem This question seems on-topic for both open data and GIS.se. No need to migrate it since it's already here.

Comment: considering how many they offload here, i'm all for sending them back

Comment: I'll leave it open since we have a nice answer. Thanks @csk

Answer (score 2):

Based on comments, it seems your data is labeled with [two-digit FIPS state codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federal_Information_Processing_Standard_state_code). (FIPS stands for Federal Information Processing Standard.)

[Here](https://www.census.gov/geo/reference/ansi_statetables.html) you can download a table with state names and FIPS codes, in this format:

> FIPS State Code | Official United States Postal Service (USPS) Code |
>   Name | Geographic Names Information System Identifier (GNISID)
>
> For example:
>
> 23|ME|Maine|01779787

You can join this table to the shapefile based on the FIPS code in your GIS software. A "join" or "table join" is a standard GIS process, it should be explained in the manual for your GIS software, as well as in many online tutorials. If you have any trouble, head over to [GIS Stack Exchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com).

Note: US localities have 5-digit FIPS codes. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIPS_county_code